# SQL - update table1 with table2 data if match found

Tags: sql

2 tables:

table1:

```
col1        col2
n100        null
n200        null
n300        null
```

table2:

```
col1        col2
n200        a
n100        b
n300        a
```

If there is a match table1 col1 = table2 col1, then UPDATE table1 col2 with table2 col2 data.

table1 RESULT:

```
col1        col2
n100        b
n200        a
n300        a
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should work nicely :

```
UPDATE table1  
SET col2 = B.col2 
FROM table1 AS A INNER JOIN table2 AS B ON A.col1 = B.col1
```

Update with join works nicely in these type of situations.